# Google maps api authorization error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I have an app with a google maps activity. This used to work just fine, but stopped working recently (not sure exactly when as I havent used the app for a month or so).

Debugging outputs the following:

```
04-01 11:49:45.240  20495-20514/com.myapp.trial10 E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
04-01 11:49:45.245  20495-20514/com.myapp.trial10 E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
04-01 11:49:45.530  20495-20517/com.myapp.trial10 E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 23
    User space API version: 23
04-01 11:49:45.530  20495-20517/com.myapp.trial10 E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014
04-01 11:50:05.030  20495-20628/com.myapp.trial10 E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
04-01 11:50:05.035  20495-20628/com.myapp.trial10 E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: **********************************
```

I have checked and the API key is correct. I have also updated everything in the SDK.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to generate a new key for some reason